# Inequivalent complete norms

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I am looking for an explicit example of two complete inequivalent norms.

Given a Banach space, I know how to explicitly construct an inequivalent complete norm. However, I am looking for an explicit example.

*Edit 1*: I came across the following here [Norm equivalence and Banach spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459082/norm-equivalence-and-banach-spaces?rq=1)

However, it does not hold that if two spaces are Banach spaces that their norm would be equivalent. Take for example the space of absolutely summable sequences and take $\sum|x_n|$ as one norm, since it is absolutely summable also the sum $\sum\frac{|x_n|}{n}$ would be convergent, but now you can consider the sequence $\delta_j$ (that's zero everywhere, except its $j$th term is $1$). You have that $\|\delta_j\|_1=1$, but $\|\delta_j\|_b = \frac1j$ you can't have the equivalence between these norms.

I want to know how the space is complete with respect to both norms.

*Edit 2*: Daniel Fischer explained in the comments why the above example is wrong. So, I'm still looking for an explicit example.

*Edit 3*: The question I asked here: [Complete Inequivalent Norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925533/complete-inequivalent-norms) asks something completely different. I'm not sure why everyone thinks it is a duplicate.

Comment: I'd be surprised if one could give an explicit example.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you please explain why?

Comment: @Surb The existence of inequivalent norms making a vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$, say, and of appropriate dimension) into a Banach space is an important fact. If there was an explicit example of a space and two such norms, it would probably be widely mentioned. I've never seen any mention of an explicit example.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, this is exactly the kind of justification I was expecting and I should say: "makes sense".

Comment: @DanielFischer, could you look at my edit and tell me if that example is incorrect?

Comment: The space $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ is not complete with the norm $\lVert x\rVert_b = \sum \lvert x_n\rvert/n$. If two norms both make the same space into a Banach space, then either the two norms are equivalent, or the two norms are incomparable. Since $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_b$ is comparable to $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert_1$, but not equivalent, the space cannot be complete with that norm.